# Pixels of an image

Tags: image-processing, camera, pixel

I have a stupid question:

I have a black circle on white background, something like:

[image]

I have a code in Matlab that gets an image with a black circle and returns the number of pixels in the circle.

**will I get the same number of pixels in a camera of 5 mega pixel and a camera of 8 mega pixel?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: *Under most circumstances, **No**. 8MP should have more pixels than 5MP, However...*

That depends on many factors related to the camera and the images that you take:

1. Focal length of the cameras, and other optics parameters. Consider a [fish-eye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisheye_lens) lens to understand my point.
2. Distance of the circle from the camera. Obviously, closer objects appear larger.
3. What the camera does with the pixels from the sensor. For example, 5MP cameras that works in a down-scaled regime, outputting 3MP instead.

Answer (score 1):

its depends on the Resolution is how many pixels you have counted horizontally or vertically when used to describe a stored image.

Higher mega pixel cameras offer the ability to print larger images.

For example a 6mp camera offers a resolution of 3000 x 2000 pixels. If you allow 300dpi (dots per inch) for print quality, this would give you a print of approx 10 in x 7 in. 3000 divided by 300 = 10, 2000 divided by 300 = approx 7
A 3.1mp camera offers a resolution of 2048 x 1536 pixels which gives a print size of 7in x 5in

Comment: thank you about your answer! I learn new thing because of you :]